# flutter navigate new screen after animatedcontainer onEnd:

Tags: flutter

I'am noob of flutter and i want a create some apps. This is my main screen with animated container.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import "./loginmenu.dart";

void main() {
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<MyApp> createState() => _MyAppState();
}

class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        backgroundColor: Color.fromRGBO(197, 197, 187, 1),
        body: AnimatedContainer(
          duration: Duration(milliseconds: 350),
          width: double.infinity,
          height: double.infinity,
          child: Image(image: AssetImage("assets/images/Babapps-logos.jpeg")),
          onEnd: () => Navigator.push(
            context,
            MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => loginscreen()),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

when animation duration finish i want go new screen.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class loginscreen extends StatefulWidget {
  const loginscreen({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        body: Column(
          children: <Widget>[
            Container(width: double.infinity, margin: EdgeInsets.all(130)),
            Container(
              width: double.infinity,
              margin: EdgeInsets.all(5),
              child: Center(
                child:
                    Text("Welcome Diet&Life", style: TextStyle(fontSize: 19)),
              ),
            ),
            Container(
              width: 320,
              margin: EdgeInsets.all(5),
              child: Center(
                child: TextField(
                  decoration: InputDecoration(
                      border: OutlineInputBorder(), hintText: "Username"),
                ),
              ),
            ),
            Container(
              width: 320,
              margin: EdgeInsets.all(5),
              child: Center(
                  child: TextField(
                decoration: InputDecoration(
                    border: OutlineInputBorder(), hintText: "Password"),
              )),
            ),
            Container(
              child: Center(
                child: RaisedButton(
                  child: Text("Login"),
                  onPressed: null,
                ),
              ),
            ),
            Container(
              margin: EdgeInsets.all(10),
              child: Center(
                child: new InkWell(
                    child: Text("Don't have an account?"), onTap: null),
              ),
            )
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  @override
  State<StatefulWidget> createState() {
    // TODO: implement createState
    throw UnimplementedError();
  }
}
```

but when I run this code, the animation does not go to the other screen even though it expires. Am I on the right track or do I have to work with setstate?

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing changing on `Container`, therefor animation `onEnd` never gets call.

You need to change something inside the container in order to animate it.

If you just like to navigate after some delay, Just use `Future.delayed` then navigate.

```dart
void main() {
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<MyApp> createState() => _MyAppState();
}

class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return const MaterialApp(home: StartPage());
  }
}

class StartPage extends StatefulWidget {
  const StartPage({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<StartPage> createState() => _StartPageState();
}

class _StartPageState extends State<StartPage> {
  Color containerColor = Colors.cyanAccent;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _nextPage();
  }

  /// just nevigate
  _nextPage() async {
    Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: 1)).then((value) {
      Navigator.push(
        context,
        MaterialPageRoute(
          builder: (context) => AnimE(),
        ),
      );
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        onPressed: () {
          setState(() {
            containerColor = Colors.blue;
          });
        },
      ),
      body: AnimatedContainer(
          duration: const Duration(seconds: 2),
          color: containerColor,
          width: double.infinity,
          height: double.infinity,
          child: const Text("a"),
          onEnd: () {
           print("Ebnd"); // paste neviagte by removing init
            //        Navigator.push(
            //   context,
            //   MaterialPageRoute(
            //     builder: (context) => loginscreen(),
            //   ),
            // );
          }),
    );
  }
}
```